# missing ) after argument list onclick, p element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting the error missing ) after argument list and I don't know why so please help me.

That's the Code

```
<p onclick='openTrackBook('" + popup.VehicleId + "', this)' class='popupStyle'>Show</p>
```

That's the outcome

```
<p onclick='openTrackBook('d435Cart67xR', this)' class='popupStyle'>Show</p>
```

Please help me
Thanks

Comment: I this you are geeration this code using MVC, You need to show MVC code using which you are generating your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic syntax of the `onclickfunction` in JavaScript:

```
onclick="openTrackBook(' + popup.VehicleId + ', this);"
```

or

```
onclick="return openTrackBook(' + popup.VehicleId + ', this);"
```

Answer (score 0):

You use ' character for your string parameter and also you used ' quote for function declaration . 
So, you should either use " or ' like:

```
<p onclick="openTrackBook(' + popup.VehicleId + ', this)" class='popupStyle'>Show</p>
```

or

```
    <p onclick='openTrackBook(" + popup.VehicleId + ", this)' class='popupStyle'>Show</p>
```

this will work. check your code. If it is issue of quotes then it will defiantly solve. if any other issue then update your question.

Answer (score 0):

try with this, i'm not to sure if popup.VheicleId is a Model but i'm assume that it is

```
 <p onclick="openTrackBook(@popup.VheicleId);" class="popupStyle">Show</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
<p onclick='openTrackBook(\"" + popup.VehicleId + "\", this)' class='popupStyle'>Show</p>
```

so that the output will be

```
<p onclick='openTrackBook("d435Cart67xR", this)' class='popupStyle'>Show</p>
```

the `'` are not matching that is why it is throwing the error

Answer (score -1):

You can't use literal `'` characters as data in attribute values delimited with `'` characters.

Either use `"` instead or use character references for them.

Answer (score -1):

You have used Single quotes for variable in function of onclick, use double quotes

```
<p onclick='openTrackBook(" + popup.VehicleId + ", this)' class='popupStyle'>Show</p>
```